# PostGIS - raster - bit operations

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I have a raster data in the database in separate rows. I would like to select 2 rows and do a bit operation with them (like `|`, `&`) and store the result in memory as a query output. Is this possible?

My databse looks like this:

```
Data | id
raster1 | 0
raster2 | 1
```

and I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT raster1 & raster2 FROM data
```

and query result are all pixels from both rasters.

Comment: I believe you could do this with [ST_MapAlgebra](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html), the 4th variant, that takes two rasters. The callback function would have to encode the logic of the | or & operations.